Set the class files directory for Latex
How, when I run the pdflatex or lualatex or similar command, can I tell Latex where to look for class files?
Let's say I have a directory structure like this:
root
|--- [my program, etc.]
|--- latex-stuff
     |--- document.latex
     |--- myclass.cls

and I call Latex from the root directory like this:
lualatex latex-stuff/document.latex

When I run that, Latex will give me an error saying File 'myclass.cls' not found. As far as I know, Latex by default only looks for classes inside the working directory and whereever the installed classes (like article) are located. But is there a way for me to add custom paths to look for classes there?
I thought there was an option like this:
lualatex --classpath=latex-stuff latex-stuff/document.latex

but there is no arg classpath and also nothing similar. So is it even possible to set that path, or is there no option to do this and I should instead try to let my program run the command from the latex-stuff directory?

You avoid a lot of problems if you cd into your latex-stuff directory and compile there.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes that'd be my workaround if it's not possibe what I want to do, I just wanted to know if it is possible

It is possible. You could add the directory to your TEXINPUTS variable, you could include the path when you call the class ... many possibilities, but why when switching to the folder is so easy?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz because I was interested. It really seems like changing the wd is the best idea. Anyways thank you!

note that all paths are relativ e to the working directory of the process not relative to the file, so if your document.latex has \input{section1.tex} then  section1.tex needs to be in the root directory with the call you show or in the latex-stuff  if you cd there first. The behaviour is consistent but massively confusing if you don't first cd to your main document so paths are relative to that location
